# C++ Disable Delayed Ack on Windows

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock

I am trying to replicate a real time application on a windows computer to be able to debug and make changes easier, but I ran into issue with Delayed Ack. I have already disabled nagle and confirmed that it improve the speed a bit. When sending a lots of small packets, window doesn't ACK right away and delay it by 200 ms. Doing more research about it, I came across [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328890/new-registry-entry-for-controlling-the-tcp-acknowledgment-ack-behavior). Problem with changing the registry value is that, it will affect the whole system rather than just the application that I am working with. Is there anyway to disable delayed ACK on window system like `TCP_QUICKACK` from linux using `setsockopt`? I tried hard coding 12, but got **WSAEINVAL** from WSAGetLastError.

I saw some dev on github that mentioned to use `SIO_TCP_SET_ACK_FREQUENCY` but I didn't see any example on how to actually use it.

So I tried doing below

```
#define SIO_TCP_SET_ACK_FREQUENCY _WSAIOW(IOC_VENDOR,23) 
result = WSAIoctl(sock, SIO_TCP_SET_ACK_FREQUENCY, 0, 0, info, sizeof(info), &bytes, 0, 0);
```

and I got **WSAEFAULT** as an error code. Please help!

Comment: By the way, you are probably solving your outer problem in a very suboptimal way. It's usually much better to fix this by fixing your application-level protocol (for example, creating opportunities for ACKs to piggyback on data) rather than by monkeying with TCP tuning. The danger with doing it the way you are doing it is that your network efficiency is much lower and that can cause very poor results on even lightly-loaded networks. If you only test under perfect conditions, it will seem the perfect solution but delayed ACK and Nagle exist for important reasons.

Comment: Thank you David! For now, I will just stay with this because the actual application code is being run on hardware with no nagle / delayed ack and in a closed loop. This was never a problem until I started running on windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen several references online that `TCP_QUICKACK` *may* actually be supported by Winsock via `setsockopt()` (opt 12), even though it is NOT documented, or officially confirmed anywhere.

But, regarding your actual question, your use of `SIO_TCP_SET_ACK_FREQUENCY` is failing because you are not providing any input buffer to `WSAIoctl()` to set the actual frequency value.  Try something like this:

```
int freq = 1; // can be 1..255, default is 2
result = WSAIoctl(sock, SIO_TCP_SET_ACK_FREQUENCY, &freq, sizeof(freq), NULL, 0, &bytes, NULL, NULL);
```

Note that `SIO_TCP_SET_ACK_FREQUENCY` is available in Windows 7 / Server 2008 R2 and later.

Comment: OMG! You are awesome. Thank you so much. That fixed my issue. For some reason SIO_TCP_SET_ACK_FREQUENCY works on win 7 as well.

Comment: Considering that default wait time is 200ms. What does freq = 1 imply? 100 ms? that would make sense since default is 2.

Comment: @tunafish24 There is some information [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/387da3ab-1430-0b1c-82b1-dae3fae0c3fc). The SET_ACK_FREQUENCY means how many packets between ACK sending. Value 1 means send ACK for every received packet.