# Set TCP_QUICKACK option in TcpClient

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I'm porting some C++ to C#. I'm struggling a bit to find equivalents to various socket options. One I can't figure out is how to set `TCP_QUICKACK` in C#.

If I have a `TcpClient`, what is the C# equivalent of:

```
optval = 1; 
setsockopt(socket_, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, &optval, sizeof(optval));
```

There doesn't *seem* to be an equivalent in `SocketOptionName`, nor does there seem to be a corresponding property in `TcpClient.Client`.

How can I set this option?

Comment: It's a requested but not implemented feature. See [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/798)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following will achieve this, but you probably need to ask yourself do you actually need to disable `TCP Delayed Acknowledgement`.  You might find the application will work fine without it.

```
// Disable TCP Delayed Acknowledgement on a socket
int SIO_TCP_SET_ACK_FREQUENCY = unchecked((int)0x98000017);
var outputArray = new byte[128];
var bytesInOutputArray = tcpClient.Client.IOControl(SIO_TCP_SET_ACK_FREQUENCY,BitConverter.GetBytes(1), outputArray);
```

The outputArray will be unchanged and bytesInOutputArray will be 0.

I have seen in a number of places over the years that TCP_QUICKACK works on Windows, albeit undocumented, it's value is 12 (same as Linux).  But you can't pass it through from C#, `Socket.SetSocketOption` will not accept it.

```
#define TCP_QUICKACK        12
```

Another undocumented option is `SIO_TCP_SET_ACK_FREQUENCY` [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55034112/c-disable-delayed-ack-on-windows) setting the frequency to a value of 1 turns off TCP Delayed Acknowledgement.

The C++ Would like this

```
    #define SIO_TCP_SET_ACK_FREQUENCY _WSAIOW(IOC_VENDOR,23) 
    result = WSAIoctl(socket, SIO_TCP_SET_ACK_FREQUENCY, &frequency, sizeof(frequency), NULL, 0, &bytes, NULL, NULL);
```